# Fatal error: Class Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator

Tags: magento2

While working with Magento theme styling suddenly i received this error from both fronend and backend. Please help me to solve this issue. I have no idea of where the exact issue.

[image]

Comment: have you changed PHP version?

Comment: I just checked and restart apache and mysql. that solved my issue. may be the issue is with php server has stopped working.